# put files in git repo when a sub directory is already in git

Tags: git

I have couple of files and directories on machine that I want to put in git.
I discovered that some of the sub directories already have .git directory.
For example:

```
parent #is the directory I want to add to git
parent/child1
parent/child2
parent/child2/.git
# all above are directories containing files.
```

When trying to add the parent I see the following:

```
git add .
warning: adding embedded git repository: child2
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> child2
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached child2
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

How can I include the child2 files in my parent repo?

Comment: When you tried, what was the effect? it's not clear what 'Add git to the parent dir' means, just running `git init` (the logical interpretation of what that probably means) will not 'do' anything except initialize a git repo.

Comment: Will the files in child dir will also be included in parent repo? -> No, unless you specify it.

Comment: how do I specify it? (without submodules)

Comment: Are you going to continue using the repository of child2? If not, I guess just removing `parent/child2/.git` is the solution.

Comment: yes, I don't want to remove child git repo, can they both live side by side?

Comment: `git add .` this is a bad habit :) - In this case you're trying to add child2/.git itself to the parent repo, though it seems to be git version dependent, I don't see that behavior. Add the files/paths you want to add, `git add child2/this; git add child2/that` and it almost certainly works. Note this is not a normal thing to do, ordinarily you'd add child2 as a dependency of the parent (either using git submodules, or the language package dependency tool). Please self answer once resolved.